# Windows 8 and Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: windows, anti-virus, windows-8-preview, releases

So, I'm about to try Windows 8 Release Preview (I've been using Developer Preview and Consumer Preview), I've heard that Microsoft Security Essentials is built-in. However, should I try to install it or I should install another antivirus (Obviously, I would have MSE + the other antivirus)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 8 has Security Essentials built-in, but [renamed to Windows Defender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender#Windows_8). You don’t need to install another antivirus.

Comment: Yes, but i've heard that it's not actually MSE but the old Windows Defender.

Comment: It’s called Windows Defender, but it’s the new MSE.

Comment: Correct, Windows Defender in Win8 = MSE. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender#Windows_8

Comment: Another Microsoft name game, drives me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

MSE is a perfectly reasonable AV for Home use, and besides, installing multiple AV alongside each other is never a good idea. If you decide to swap, make sure you uninstall MSE first.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to unistall the MSE or Windows Defender that it comes with Windows 8.

Comment: You can disable it to install another AV software of your choice, but there is no approved method for uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you want. MSE *should* eventually, [least with release versions disable itself](http://techreport.com/discussions.x/23044) when another AV is installed and up to date. There will very likely be a way to manually disable it i suppose.

[Internet scuttlebutt](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1081101-antivirus-for-windows-8-release-preview/) also indicates many common AVs seem to work, but you may need to find a windows 8 specific version for some.